# Testing mobx react observer with react usecontext - React, Mobx

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, react-testing-library, mobx-react-lite

New to testing mobx with React. I'm testing a a simple side navigation bar, open/closes on hamburger menu.  I have set up a store for the Navbar:

```
export class Store {

    toggle = false;

    setToggle(bool){
        this.toggle = bool;
    };
};

decorate(Store, {
    toggle: observable,
    setToggle: action
});

export default createContext(new Store());
```

And here is the Navbar component:

```
export default observer(() => {
    const store = useContext(Store); //SideNavStore is imported from mobx store folder

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        store.setToggle(false);
    }

    return(
        <div data-testid="test">
            <Drawer open={store.toggle} onClose={handleOnClick}>
                <div role="presentation">
                    <List>
                        {routes.map(route => {

                            return   <>
                                        <ListItem button onClick={handleOnClick}>
                                            <ListItemText primary={route.name}/>
                                        </ListItem>
                                    </>

                        })}
                    </List>
                </div>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
});
```

This is App.js

```
export default () => {

    return (
      <div className="App">


        <Navbar ></Navbar>

      </div >
    )
  }
```

Test.js

```
describe('Navbar Interaction', () => {

    describe('Inpsecting Navbar Contents', () => {

        beforeEach(cleanup);

        class Store {
            sideNavToggle = true;
        }

        const DecoratedStore = decorate(Store,{
            sideNavToggle: observable
        });

        const renderWithStore = (store) => {
            render(
                    <Navbar />
            );
        }

        it('Expect links are present', () => {
            const store = new DecoratedStore();
            const { getByText } = renderWithStore(store);
            expect(getByText("My Dashboard")).toBeTruthy();
        });

    });
})
```

My test here fails because it can't find the text in the document, `Drawer Open` is set to `false` configured by the `store.toggle`. Trying to figure out how to inject the store or dummy store in the test, there are some tutorials about using Provider/Inject but that requires `mobx-react` and I believe they are deprecated; I would like to stick with `mobx-react-lite`. In `renderWithStore`, I'm stuck on how to pass the dummy store in the test. I could pass the store as a `props` but I believe that requires `provider/inject` which I don't want to do that if necessary.  I rather import the store directly in the Navbar component using `React.useContext`. I don't see tests using `React.useContext` and `Mobx Observer` in the web. Has anyone encountered this type of scenario or can you provide a better approach? Also what is the best practice with using React and Mobx stores?  Using `React-testing-library` for my tests. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`mobx-react-lite` does advice users to prefer `React.useContext` over provider/inject.

Take a look at https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context

```
const storeContext = React.createContext<TStore | null>(null)

export const StoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const store = useLocalStore(createStore)
  return <storeContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</storeContext.Provider>
}
```

As for testing, if you want the component to use custom store or a mock store, you could do it by passing-in the store to StoreProvider. This how Redux users test their components.

```
export const StoreProvider = ({ store, children }) => {
  return <storeContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</storeContext.Provider>
}
```